# heap sort may be considered as insertion sort or selection sort done on a heap data structure instead of a list? Which one will it be?

Tags: data-structures, selection, insertion, heapsort

Heap sort may be considered
as

```
A. Insertion sort done on a heap data structure instead of a list.
B. Selection sort done on a heap data structure instead of a list.
C. Bubble sort done on a heap data structure instead of a list.
D. None of the above.
```

Comment: What do you think the answer is? We're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be `B`.

As when doing the min or max `heapify` during Heap Sort we retrieve the min or max element respectively from the whole heap and place it on the `root` of the heap.

Selection Sort does the same thing. Finding min/max element from the array and place it at arr[0]. Then again find min/max element from the rest of the array and place it at arr[1] and so on.